# Where can I find the list of NCIC assisiged "Originating Agency Identifier"?

Tags: usa, database, crime

From the docs, provided on the [National Incident-Based Reporting System (NIBRS) user manual](https://ucr.fbi.gov/nibrs/nibrs-user-manual),

> An Originating Agency Identifier (ORI) is a unique nine-character identifier the National Crime Information Center (NCIC) has assigned to each LEA in coordination with the CSO. The Uniform Crime Reporting (UCR) Program uses this identifier to indicate the contributing agency. Data Element 1 is mandatory in each NIBRS submission.

But there is no information on where I can get the list of Originating Agency Identifiers, and I don't see it on the [Downloads Page](https://crime-data-explorer.fr.cloud.gov/downloads-and-docs). Where can I find that list? Preferably authoritative from a government site, that I can redistribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## API (clean data)

It's available at the [Crime Data API end point](https://crime-data-explorer.fr.cloud.gov/api), you have to first [request a data.gov api key](https://api.data.gov/signup/) then you can access it on

```
https://api.usa.gov/crime/fbi/sapi/api/agencies?api_key=<api_key>
```

This is documented on the [GitHub project crime-data-api](https://github.com/fbi-cde/crime-data-api), and the official [Crime Data API page](https://crime-data-explorer.fr.cloud.gov/api).

On Dec 20, 2018, the result of the API call is 7.7MB of JSON.

## Alternatively

Go to the [Crime Data Explorer page under the section *"Explore by location and data set"*](https://crime-data-explorer.fr.cloud.gov/) and click on the link under the map,

[image: map with link]

Comment: Just to add to Evan's answer for anyone stumbling upon this Q&A: I just fetched the data (2020-06-12) and wrote a quickie Python script to convert it to flat CSV, which I've uploaded to this Google Sheet for easy download: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UC-KdQqXKUD5xAQZdmQnBcJ_u02wCe21Cco7nOhfsqA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Ironically, I found the [front end project's docs](https://github.com/fbi-cde/crime-data-frontend) more helpful for finding out how to make API requests than the API project's docs.

Answer (score 2):

You can download a comprehensive file through UMich's ICPSR repository (sign up is free):

https://www.icpsr.umich.edu/web/ICPSR/series/366

Here's a sample of the data – I believe the ICPSR's ToC doesn't allow publicly redistributing the full copy, but you'll get an idea of what it contains before signing up:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ASnQUPUyKhELtzY3MZlTBeRm2WdbhmbrfalWjGQ3ojk/edit#gid=0

Some more context (I asked for this on Twitter and someone helpfully showed me the way): https://twitter.com/dancow/status/1270704381634150402

Answer (score 1):

This is from circa 1981, but as of this date it is still very accurate. I believe the number issued by the FBI lasts the life of the agency, unless the ORI has been revoked for violations.

https://www.ojp.gov/ncjrs/virtual-library/abstracts/national-law-enforcement-telecommunications-systems-ori-originating